# For what value of b is $g(x)$ continuous at every $x$?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

For what value of $b$ is $g(x)$ continuous at every $x$?

$$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x-b}{b+1},  & x<0 \\
x^2+b, & x>0
\end{cases}$$
Should we set $x = 0$ for both pieces and then equate them? Or?

Comment: As written, it cannot be; the two cases are written to exclude $x=0$ in the first place.  If one of them were to be $\le$ or $\ge$ then that's how you'd do it, though you do also need to be careful -- if $b = -1$ then the first part has division by zero problems.

Comment: Are you sure you have written the bounds correctly? If one of the bounds included $x=0$ then $b=0$ and $b=-2$ would yield continuity.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the question is incomplete or poorly phrased. For the function $g$ to be continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, it must be continuous at $x=0$. In other words, the function $g$ must be defined at $x=0$. You haven't defined $g(0)$. Probably, the question was to find a value of $g(0)$ so that the function $g$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$. If that is the case, it is easy to check that the function $g$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ for every $b\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}$.

To be continuous at $x=0$, we must have $-\dfrac{b}{b+1}=b$, which yields $b\in\{0,-2\}$.

If $b=0$, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)=0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^-}g(x)=0$. If $b=-2$, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)=-2$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^-}g(x)=-2$.

In other words, for the function $g$ to be continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ we must set  $g(0):=0$, $b:=0$ or $g(0):=-2$, $b:=-2$.